# Gunicorn async workers (gevent) not working with Django-Oscar: 500 Internal server error

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, gevent, django-oscar

**Brief**

Django-Oscar web application running in production and staging environment, hosted in virtual environment, running as systemd daemon using Gunicorn.

Nginx is used as proxy, gunicorn is working normally left to the default "worker-class" which is "sync", but its not suitable for our case, I need to change it to async, specifically "gevent", usually its done by adding the following parameters to ExecStart

```
--worker-class gevent --worker-connections 768
```

But the workers did not start and I got the following error

```
[2017-08-15 08:42:35 +0000] [25425] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-08-15 08:42:35 +0000] [25425] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2017-08-15 08:42:35 +0000] [25425] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/myapp.sock (25425)
[2017-08-15 08:42:35 +0000] [25425] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2017-08-15 08:42:35 +0000] [25430] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25430
[2017-08-15 08:42:35 +0000] [25425] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2017-08-15 11:42:37 +0000] [25430] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 190, in init_process
    super(GeventWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myapp/main/checkout/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from main.shipping.models import ShippingPeriod
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myapp/main/shipping/models.py", line 57, in <module>
    from oscar.apps.shipping.models import *  # noqa
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/apps/shipping/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from oscar.apps.shipping import abstract_models
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/apps/shipping/abstract_models.py", line 12, in <module>
    Scale = loading.get_class('shipping.scales', 'Scale')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 29, in get_class
    return get_classes(module_label, [classname], module_prefix)[0]
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 100, in get_classes
    local_module = _import_module(local_module_label, classnames)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 121, in _import_module
    return __import__(module_label, fromlist=classnames)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named scales
[2017-08-15 11:42:37 +0000] [25430] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25430)
[2017-08-15 08:42:37 +0000] [25425] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-08-15 08:42:37 +0000] [25425] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

After reading and trying many solutions, I tried --preload in the mix, and it got the workers up, but unfortunately for some reason its causing the application to return internal server error (500)

```
[2017-08-15 14:44:51 +0000] [26323] [DEBUG] GET /
[2017-08-15 14:44:51 +0000] [26323] [ERROR] Error handling request /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 56, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 152, in handle_request
    super(GeventWorker, self).handle_request(*args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 107, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myapp/oscarapi/middleware.py", line 16, in <module>
    from oscarapi.basket.operations import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myapp/oscarapi/basket/operations.py", line 22, in <module>
    Applicator = get_class('offer.applicator', 'Applicator')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 29, in get_class
    return get_classes(module_label, [classname], module_prefix)[0]
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 100, in get_classes
    local_module = _import_module(local_module_label, classnames)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oscar/core/loading.py", line 121, in _import_module
    return __import__(module_label, fromlist=classnames)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/builtins.py", line 93, in __import__
    result = _import(*args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named applicator

==> /var/log/nginx/access.log <==
10.0.52.154 - - [15/Aug/2017:11:44:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
```

Can someone kindly point me in the right direction :)
Thanks in advance everyone!

**Update**
I also tried eventlet since gevent is not working, and I get this

```
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7481] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
proxy_protocol: False
  worker_connections: 768
  statsd_host: None
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x7f1637e18938>
  errorlog: /tmp/logging.log
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  worker_class: eventlet
  ssl_version: 2
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  syslog: False
  syslog_facility: user
  when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x7f1637e18668>
  pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x7f1637e187d0>
  cert_reqs: 0
  preload_app: False
  keepalive: 2
  accesslog: None
  group: 1000
  graceful_timeout: 30
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  spew: False
  workers: 3
  proc_name: None
  sendfile: None
  pidfile: None
  umask: 0
  on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x7f1637e18500>
  pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x7f1637e18ed8>
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  limit_request_fields: 100
  pythonpath: None
  on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x7f1637e1e758>
  config: None
  logconfig: None
  check_config: False
  statsd_prefix: 
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  reload_engine: auto
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x7f1637e1e0c8>
  post_request: <function post_request at 0x7f1637e1e1b8>
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x7f1637e18c08>
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
  threads: 1
  max_requests: 0
  chdir: /home/ubuntu
  daemon: False
  user: 1000
  limit_request_line: 4094
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  certfile: None
  on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x7f1637e18398>
  post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x7f1637e18aa0>
  child_exit: <function child_exit at 0x7f1637e1e320>
  worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x7f1637e1e488>
  paste: None
  default_proc_name: myapp.wsgi:application
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog_prefix: None
  ciphers: TLSv1
  worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x7f1637e18d70>
  loglevel: debug
  bind: ['unix:/tmp/myapp.sock']
  raw_env: []
  initgroups: False
  capture_output: False
  reload: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x7f1637e1e5f0>
  timeout: 30
  keyfile: None
  ca_certs: None
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  backlog: 2048
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7481] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7481] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7481] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/myapp.sock (7481)
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7481] [INFO] Using worker: eventlet
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7486] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7486
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7487] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7487
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7487] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 102, in init_process
    self.patch()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 91, in patch
    hubs.use_hub()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 70, in use_hub
    mod = get_default_hub()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 38, in get_default_hub
    import eventlet.hubs.epolls
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/epolls.py", line 27, in <module>
    from eventlet.hubs.hub import BaseHub
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 23, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greenlets as greenlet, clear_sys_exc_info, monotonic, six
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/monotonic.py", line 167, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('no suitable implementation for this system')
RuntimeError: no suitable implementation for this system
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7486] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 102, in init_process
    self.patch()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 91, in patch
    hubs.use_hub()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 70, in use_hub
    mod = get_default_hub()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 38, in get_default_hub
    import eventlet.hubs.epolls
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/epolls.py", line 27, in <module>
    from eventlet.hubs.hub import BaseHub
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 23, in <module>
    from eventlet.support import greenlets as greenlet, clear_sys_exc_info, monotonic, six
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/myapp-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/support/monotonic.py", line 167, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('no suitable implementation for this system')
RuntimeError: no suitable implementation for this system
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7486] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7486)
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7487] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7487)
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7481] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-08-16 07:19:30 +0000] [7481] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```